# Permutations: Ball Bearings to be shared

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Nineteen identical ball bearings are to be randomly shared by two girls and three boys
anyhow. What is the probability that the boys will receive one ball bearing each and
the rest go to the girls?

Comment: The _a priori_ probability that two girls and three boys are going to be sharing ball bearings in the first place is zero.

Comment: The answer to this problem is actually not zero. The solution is 17/8855, but I'm having trouble arriving to it.

Comment: I was making a joke, sorry...

Answer (score 1):

By Stars and Bars, there are $\binom{19+5-1}{5-1}$ ways to distribute the ball bearings between the children.  For we are counting the solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_5=19$ in non-negative integers.

Let us assume that these $\binom{23}{4}$ possibilities are *all equally likely.*  This is in my view an unreasonable model, but it is the model the problem-setter intends be used.

We now count the "favourables." Of these $\binom{23}{4}$ ways, there are $17$ where each boy has $1$, for we must distribute the remaining $16$ between the girls, and the older girl can have anywhere from $0$ to $16$.

**Remark:** If we are not given any information about the distribution process, I think it is more reasonable to assume that the bearings are given, one at a time, to a randomly chosen child. That produces a sample space of $5^{19}$ equally likely elements, and an answer different from the "official" $\frac{17}{\binom{23}{4}}$.

Comment: Thank you so much Andre! Beautifully explained for me. You have been more than a great deal of help. When attempting this problem, I was able to compute the sample space of '23 choose 4', but when computing the number of outcomes in the event that each of the three boys receive one ball bearing, I made the mistake of saying its 16 (since there are 16 ball bearings left) choose 2, which, after going through your solution, was completely the wrong way of thinking about it. Thanks once again.

Comment: You are welcome. One can also get the number of ways for the girls by Stars and Bars as $\binom{16+2-1}{2-1}$, but that's kind of overkill.